# Load AJAX form on every page via drupal_get_form

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm trying to load this contact form on every page via drupal_get_form()

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['contact'] = array(
        'title' => t('Contact'),
        'description' => t('Contact'),
        'page callback' => 'contact_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    ); 
    return $items;
}

function contact_page () {
     $output = '<div id="ajax_contact_form">'.drupal_render(drupal_get_form('ajax_contact_form')).'</div>'; 
}

function ajax_contact_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit', 
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_contact_callback', 
            'wrapper' => 'ajax_contact_form', 
            'name' => 'submit1',
            'method' => 'html', 
            'progress' => array(
                    'type' => 'throbber',
                    'message' => t('Message is sending...'),
                ),
        ),
    '#value' => t('Send'),
    );
    $form['box'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup', 
    '#prefix' => '<div id="box">', 
    '#suffix' => '</div>', 
    );
  return $form;
}

function ajax_contact_callback($form, &$form_state){
    drupal_validate_form('ajax_contact_form', $form, $form_state);
    $name =  $form_state['values']['name'];
    if (form_get_errors()) {

        $form['box']['#markup']='<div class="ajax_message ajax_error" >'.t('Please check your fields!').'</div>';
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
        return $form;
    }
    return $form;
}
?>
```

Basically everything is works on /contact page but when I try to load this form from page.tpl.php. It doesn't want to validate. What should I do?

```
<?php  print render(drupal_get_form('ajax_contact_form'));  ?>
```

Here

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, problem was in `'wrapper'` so this is how it works

```
<?php  print '<div id="ajax_contact_form">'.drupal_render(drupal_get_form('ajax_contact_form')).'</div>';  ?>
```

Comment: I would advise either implementing a custom block to output this (and placing the block in a theme region), or fetching the form in theme_preprocess_page, and passing that as a variable to the template to render. No need to print html within ```print```, just wrap it. You could also add that HTML as prefix/suffix on the form array in the form builder code.